# Car share in Las Vegas?

Tags: car-rentals, las-vegas, ride-sharing

My boyfriend and I are flying into Las Vegas but would prefer not to rent a car through the usual Hertz, Dollar Rental etc. Does anyone know of a reliable car share program in Vegas? Something where we could rent a car from someone for a reasonable rate for a few days.

Answer (score 4):

Las Vegas had one of the most ambitious shared transportation schemes in the country, including shared Tesla Model S sedans, managed by a company called Shift. In the end, [Shift went defunct](https://lasvegasweekly.com/as-we-see-it/2015/jul/01/shift-downtown-car-sharing-venture-exits-zach-ware/) in 2015; they could not keep up with their own hype.

Las Vegas did attract traditional car sharing service **[ZipCar](http://www.zipcar.com/)**, which is owned by Avis Budget Group. The [Las Vegas rates page](http://www.zipcar.com/check-rates/lasvegas) at this time appears to be broken, however. For services where you rent a private individual's car, as opposed to a fleet vehicle, I am only aware of **[Turo](https://turo.com/)** and **[JustShareIt](http://justshareit.com/)**, both of which do have vehicles in Las Vegas, though not much of a selection.

Otherwise, I would note that Las Vegas, as a tourist hub, has very competitive rental car rates as well as plentiful taxis and other transportation options.

Comment: I can confirm as a Zipcar member that the rates page shows up properly, on the members-only website.